# numpy.genfromtxt flattens my data

Tags: python, numpy

I have `row.csv`

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

and `column.csv`

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5
```

`numpy.genfromtxt("one-of-the-above.csv", delimiter=",")` reads them into the same array: `np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

but I would like to get distinct 2D arrays instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a "feature" of [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).  Before it returns the data that it read from the file, it uses [`numpy.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to eliminate trivial dimensions.

If you use [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) instead, you can use the argument `ndmin=2` to ensure that the result is always a two-dimensional array.

For example:

```
In [15]: !cat one_row.csv
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

In [16]: !cat one_col.csv
1
2
3
4
5

In [17]: np.loadtxt('one_row.csv', delimiter=',', ndmin=2)
Out[17]: array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])

In [18]: np.loadtxt('one_col.csv', delimiter=',', ndmin=2)
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]])
```

If you would like to see this option added to `genfromtxt`, add a comment or a "thumbs up" to the issue that I created for it here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4811